# Replace $j with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I am having an interesting issue. I am using the jQuery function `clone()` in a google chrome extension. The function is cloning a table row. The problem is that the TR has some inline javascript/jquery in it using `$j()` instead of `jQuery()`.

Every time I try to output the cloned row I get the error "$j is not defined".

So I thought of 2 possible solutions for this issue:

1. Make my chrome extension work with `$j()` (tried using jquery no conflict) intead of `jQuery()`

or

1. Do a search in the cloned item before outputting it, replace `$j` with `jQuery`.

My problem is that I cannot accomplish either...

```
 var rows = jQuery("#field-mapping-template").clone(true);
 rows.insertBefore("#field-mapping-template");
```

Comment: Any reason not to write `window.$j = jQuery`?

Comment: are you wanting to run the js/jQ when you output the clone or just have it assigned to the page elements?

Comment: Could you show us the code that uses $j()?

Comment: Douglas - using window.$j = jQuery works... but unfotunately this approach on work anyway... because I just noticed that there are other variables in the cloned element that are available in the original script,but that chrome won't recognize. Please post that as the answer to this post and I will mark it as completed.

Answer (score 5):

I mean, I wouldn't really recommend doing this but you can *if you really need to*.

Go into the development version of jQuery and scroll all the way down to the bottom until you see this line of code:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Now simply change it to:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$j = jQuery;
```

Now when you write a script like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="test" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(function () {
        alert($j('input').val());
    });
</script>
```

Instead of `$`, it will work for `$j`.

This is different than replacing `jQuery()`. The `$` is short hand for `jQuery()`.

**I would really, really, really not recommend replacing `jQuery()` with $j or anything for that matter.**

As of the latest release (v1.7.2), there are **879 references to the `jQuery` object** in the development code that you would have to change to `$j`.

If you have a good find and replace, you can do it, *but I would not recommend doing it*.

Comment: I voted it up David, not sure why anyone would vote down.. Excellent answer.