# Use of $j in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what the $J means in this javascript excerpt?

```
if ($J('.searchView.federatedView.hidden').attr('style') === 'display: block;' || $J('.searchView.federatedView.shown').length > 0) {

 federatedKey = $J('.searchView.federatedView').attr('id').split('searchView')[1];
 federatedKey = '_'+federatedKey;
```

Is this JQuery??

cheers

Comment: Yes, looks like jQuery. Normally you use jQ with `$` but if that is problematic for some reason it can be changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace $j with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127577/replace-j-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like jQuery in a noconflict mode:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/